# Problem with JCarouselLite in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm using JCarouselLite on my website [www.peach-designs.com](http://www.peach-designs.com) and my problem is when it loads in Chrome, the entire page doesn't load - just the navigation bar, rather than the image scroller I have. When I click 'Home on the navigation bar, everything displays fine (index.php), but not the initial load (which should ideally be index.php shouldn't it).

I have had advice that the problem is JCarousel, my other problem is, I have JCarouselLite with no control buttons or anything, and the code looks completely different to JCarousel. Is there anybody who has encountered this problem with JCarouselLite who can help?

Hope you can help,

Kind Regards,

Snakespan

Comment: When and where are you initializing jCarouselLite in your code?

Comment: I managed to fix this after, I didn't declare the width and height of the images in the html and this appeared to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
$(window).load()
```

rather than

```
$(document).ready()
```

, it works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Full working code after I applied Kainnan fix:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#prodCarousel").jCarouselLite({
        auto: 7000,
        speed: 1500,
        scroll: 4,
        visible: 4
    });
});
```