# JCarouselLite Fallback in Safari/Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari

I was wondering if there is a way to use a fallback option if the browser the website is opened in is Safari or Chrome?

At the moment my problem is with JCarouselLite which is not working properly when the home page loads, so I was wondering if someone knew of a way to counter this by disabling javascript in those browsers?

The full description of the problem I'm having is on [Problem with JCarouselLite in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014668/problem-with-jcarousellite-in-chrome).

Hope someone can help,

Kind Regards,

Snakespan

Answer (score 1):

Put your jCarouselLite script in the `window.onLoad()` function.

For example

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#car_scroller").jCarouselLite({
            btnNext: ".next",
            btnPrev: ".prev",
            visible: 7,
            scroll: 7
        });               
    });
```